# show onscreenkeyboard when type in QLineEdit in Qt

Tags: qt, show-hide, qlineedit, on-screen-keyboard

I want to show **osk.exe(onscreenkeyboard)** when click on the **QLineEdit** and when focus out osk.exe **hide** or **minimized**?
how can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `QProcess` and reimplement the methods `QLineEdit::focusInEvent` and `QLineEdit::focusOutEvent`. Try implement a class inheriting from `QLineEdit` like this:

```
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QProcess>

class MyLineEdit: public QLineEdit
{
public:
    MyLineEdit(QWidget * parent = 0): QLineEdit(parent) 
    {
        process_ = new QProcess();
    }

protected:
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent * e)
    {
        QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
        process_->start("start C:\\osk.exe"); 
    }
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent * e)
    {
        QLineEdit::focusOutEvent(e);
        process_->kill(); 
    }

private:
    QProcess * process_;
}
```

(Of course replace `C:\\osk.exe` by the exact address of this osk.exe).

Then just use a `MyLineEdit` instead of a `QLineEdit`, it should work. I do not know how to hide or minimize the process, so I decided to kill it and restart it if necessary instead ;-)